# How to sketch fibres in the coordinate plane

Tags: geometry

I always struggle in the "easy" or introductory problems in a given subject. And then I get going. For example, given that the "fibre of f at b" is the set {a in A | f(a)=b}, how do I describe the fibers of v for v(x)=|x|? Is the empty set a fibre of V according to the given definition?

This problem has been sitting on my head for hours!!!

Thanks.

Comment: What I'm thinking is that the empty set is not a fibre because the fibres of v are all the points on the nonzero x-axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$v(x)=|x|$ is your function. You have to take a fiber over a point, or better, a number.

For example, the fiber over $2$ is all vectors with length $2$ (a sphere).

Comment: But this is in R^2! And we're not discussing vector lengths here, right?

Comment: @AbhishekMallela, I don't know. Your question is not so clear. You talked about coordinate plane so I supposed that. What is the domain of $v$? What is $|\cdot|$ to you? For me, it is the norm (absolute value if $x$ is a real number).

Comment: For me also, it is absolute value if x is a real number. But the domain of v is all reals

Comment: It is easy. For any positive number $r$ you can find exactly two numbers with $r$ as absolute value: $r,-r$.